# css responsive theme image break layout

Tags: css, image, themes

Hi and thanks for reading, am building this site http://myspacioclub.com and am using a wordpress responsive theme, and I got this image "bannerfb" with class "banner" that was asked for the customer. So inside the space for the logo I create a new div to put the banner and added this properties to the div of the banner:

.banner {
 `position:relative;`
 `top:-170px;`
 `left:450px;`
}

but as the theme is responsive, when i make windows smaller like the size of tablet or cellphone the layout breaks, can someone help me?
How could I fix the theme that only use the banner properties when the window is in a bigger resolution, or any similar solution but the idea is to keep the banner with those properties without been affected by the smaller size.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with us?

Comment: If you read carefully you can see he provided us with address to website ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this different ways, but one way is following: First wrap your logo and banner in a div

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="">
            <img src="http://myspacioclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Myspacioclub.png"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <img src="http://myspacioclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bannerfb.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.banner {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
.banner img, .logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can see [working example in here](http://jsfiddle.net/z84mS/). Also, I have to point out, that at least at the moment you are using more than 7000px width image in your banner. This is NOT what you should do. You banner, at least in with my screen, is 700px wide. DO NOT ever use bigger images than you need. It shows 700px wide image, but you still have to load the 7000px one. Convert to smaller size! If you necessarily need bigger image for big screens, you could use javascript or css `@media` tag to load different image for different screen size. For that you have to set your banner image as background not as `<img>` and then do something like this in CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
    .banner { background: url(path/to/image); }
}
```

You can set many steps like this. Just add another one, change the `min-width` and load different image to background.

So in your page you have to do following in CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1320px){
    .span8 { width:1178px; }
}
    .name-logo, .banner { width: 50%; }
    .banner img { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    .name-logo img { width: auto; height: auto; }
    .name-logo { float: left; }
    .banner { float: right; }
```

Trick with responsive layout is to use percentage values not fixed pixel ones and do not use negative margins if possible.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i try that method but didn't work for me, i did separate the div's and wrapped into one but then it rip all the theme, now i got just the div separated and it's fine because it does change the size but how can i make that the banner moves to the right of the logo just when is more or equal at the size of normal browser?

Comment: I must say you have very weird and incredibly messed up markup there. You did all this .row and span's markup? Why so many negative margins?
and Trick with responsive layout is not to use fixed widths. Use percentages. I will edit my answer and try it to fit your mark up. Wait.

Comment: @GabouhLopez You are using: `[class*="span"]` in your CSS. This looks very not nice and I really have no idea why you need this? First time seeing something like that.
p.s. Please do not forget to accept an answer and/or up-vote ;)

Comment: great, i already did it and it works, now i got this doubt, i try to increase the span 8 to a width 1170px so i can increase the name-logo and banner, but then i notice there are other span 8 that are been afected, what could i do to increase it, without afecting the other and still making that piece responsive, to not just let the image with logo be in the left side of the header?

Comment: I must say you theme CSS is horribly coded. Very hard to make any changes in layout. Waay too many unnecessary html markup. Ok I'll check it out once more, but it seems like too big hassle to be worth it.

Comment: Well at least in my opinion, you should not write CSS like this, but ok. Here is what you have to do. Search for: `@media (min-width: 320px)` in you CSS file and change `span8` to have `width: 1178px`.

Comment: @GabouhLopez sry, mistake in previous comment. not min-width: 320px, but 1320px. I also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: p.s. If you want you logo to be original size, then just remove the 100% rule and change it to `auto` for both, width and height, but keep the .banner img { 100% } I made an edit in my answer accoringly.

Comment: @GabouhLopez The other span8's you mentioned about, leave those alone. Just change the span8 which is at line:4590, between `@media (min-width: 1320px){}` And Please do not forget to up-vote and accept my answer!

Comment: Sorry for late response, yesterday was very late hehe and i couldn't handle the sleep, yeah thanks a lot now i make the banner to be resposive and now i learned more of responsive, i coulnd't make that the banner literally move from one position to another at the bigger point of a normal screen browser, and i try that about span 8 but still break all the layout and rip the sidebar, so i just add a id to the span 8 and give width of 98% + margin-top:-1%; and it workout, now at least i check on my browser and does not break at all. Thanks for the help Ruuter.